# How to use Protocols objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, inheritance, protocols

I need to inherit Picker selected values into the other place .I am trying the below code but null value is coming ..please check where I am going wrong.
I have to Inherit String values that is been passes in the `PickerView`..please check the code

**Picker1.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol pickerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)didFinishPicking:(NSString *)pickedStr;

@end
@interface
@property(nonatomic,retain)id<pickerDelegate>delegate;
```

**picker.m**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {


 string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[list objectAtIndex:row]];

 label.text=string;

 [self.delegate didFinishPicking:string];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];


list =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[list addObject:@"a"];
[list addObject:@"b"];    

}
```

**Acitivity_1.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Picker1.h"
@interface Activity_1 : UIViewController<UIApplicationDelegate, pickerDelegate>{

@property(nonatomic,retain)Picker1 *delegate1;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *str;

@end
```

**Activity_1.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
 **this is how i print the value but value is null**
 NSLog(@"delegate1%@",self.delegate1.string);


delegate1 = [[Picker1 alloc] init];

[delegate1 setDelegate : self];


}

-(void)didFinishPicking:(NSString *)pickedStr
{
[self setStr:pickedStr];
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation about [Protocols](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594-CH1-SW1)

Comment: ya I already read this..but can you let me know where i m wrong in code

Comment: Try reading the documentation about [Delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) as well then

Comment: yaone thing i m confused thatI defined the delegate in didselectrow in picker1...and returning in viewdidload...is it possible...even i tried the - (void)applicationWillBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification;...not works

Comment: you didn't define your delegate in the didselectRow method you are invoking a method on your delegate instead. The set-up of your delegate happens when you call this: [delegate1 setDelegate : self];

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out a value of a delegate just before you are setting it up....so it will print null. You should print out your string when the didFinishPicking method is called instead since this is where you are setting up your string.

```
-(void)didFinishPicking:(NSString *)pickedStr
{
    [self setStr:pickedStr];

    // print the string you have just picked here if you want
    NSLog(@"Picked string: %@",pickedStr);
}
```

**Note one the side:** avoid any name convention with number such as Activity_1, Picker1 this is extremely bad code practice.

Comment: no if i use here...its not even displaying `delegate1`or null..i think..method is not been called

Comment: did u debug within the didFinishPicking method?

Comment: Is ur didSelectRow method at least called with self.delegate being not null?

Comment: you mean i should nslog in Didselectrow... NSLog(@"did select %@",self.delegate);...its null

Comment: it means then that your delegate is not set-up when you are invoking it in the Didselecthrow method. Since it is null the didFinishPicking method won't be called.

Comment: use break points when you are setting your delegate and when you are invoking your method on your delegate to get an understanding of what's goin wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are NSLogging delegate before creating self.delegate1 itself
Please use the below lines of code.

```
delegate1 = [[Picker1 alloc] init];
[delegate1 setDelegate : self];
```

And put NSLog inside "didFinishPicking"

```
-(void)didFinishPicking:(NSString *)pickedStr
{
 NSLog(@"pickedStr%@", pickedStr);
 [self setStr:pickedStr];
}
```

Comment: yes because the string's delegate is even not set-up in the view didLoad method but self.delegate1 is not null at least

Comment: ya i did this...but  `NSLog(@"pickedStr%@", pickedStr);` is not been called ...didFinishPicking is not called